# jython classnotfoundexception even if class file exists

Tags: jython-2.5

I am using jython and calling some custom Java API and I added all the jars I needed or I am using in my code and jython still complains about one class as it couldnt find (NoClassDefFoundError), I am not sure why, I checked all my jars in path and I have that class in one of those jars that are in path.

This is how I am running my code

```
jython -Dpython.path=a.jar:b.jar:c.jar client.py
```

and it complains about a class that is in c.jar, any idea why it happens. am I missing some extra options for jython (I am not including the jython.jar in this path)

EDIT: I was trying to figure this out myself and I found that adding the same jar files to CLASSPATH (like export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:a.jar:b.jar...) and running jython client.py worked fine.
This is a strange behavior, I am glad I am out of this issue sooner than I thought

Answer (score 0):

I think jython expects Java-Classes on the Classpath ...

maybe that will help:

[Classloader Trouble](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/Classloader-trouble-td1778425.html)